# relationship between java applications and jbpm

Tags: java, jbpm

Is there any way for relationship between java applications and jbpm?
For example start The process belongs to JBoss JBPM by java (SE) application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jBPM is a Java application, so you can embed it in your own application, or use the Remote Java client to remotely connect to a jBPM execution server and execute the request there.